# how to put css in selected row in angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i am creating a todo list in angularjs.. its almost done.. my question is when i click on edit button, i want to highlight full row which is in editing mode by adding a css class "yellow"...
but i have no idea how to do this...

and can anybody tell me is my way of coding is right or worng.. please

**jsfiddle link**

http://jsfiddle.net/mcVfK/1338/

here is my code

**html**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <h3>Todo List</h3>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="create your todos" ng-model="newItem">
        <p class="help-block text-center red" ng-show="!newItem && empty">*Fill the field.</p>
        <br>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Todo</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="todoList in todoLists">
                    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{todoList.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{todoList.edit}}</td>
                    <td><a class="btn {{disabled}} pull-right" href="" ng-click="remove(todoList)">delete</a>
                        <a class="btn {{disabled}} pull-right" href="" ng-click="edit($index)">edit</a> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="add()" ng-hide="editMode">ADD</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="update(newItem)" ng-show="editMode">UPDATE</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

**my js file**

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.empty = false;
    $scope.editMode = false;

    $scope.todoLists = [{name : "one", edit : "false"},{name : "two", edit : "false"}];

    $scope.add = function(){
        if(!$scope.newItem == ""){
            $scope.todoLists.push({name:$scope.newItem, edit:"false"});
            $scope.newItem = "";
            $scope.empty = false;
        }else{
            $scope.empty = true;
        };
    };

    $scope.remove = function(item){
        var index = $scope.todoLists.indexOf(item);
        $scope.todoLists.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.edit = function(index){
        $rootScope.ind = index;
        $scope.newItem = $scope.todoLists[$rootScope.ind].name;
        $scope.editMode = true;
        $scope.disabled = "disabled";
        $scope.todoLists[index].edit = "true";
    };

    $scope.update = function(item){
        if(!$scope.newItem == ""){  
            $scope.todoLists[$rootScope.ind].name = item;
            $scope.todoLists[$rootScope.ind].edit = "false";
            $scope.editMode = false;
            $scope.newItem = "";
            $scope.disabled = "";
        }else{
            $scope.empty = true;
        };
    };


}]);
```

**css file**

```
.yellow{
        background:yellow;
    }
    .red{
        color:red;
    }
```

Comment: you want to use `ng-class`

Comment: yeh i know but ... i dont know how ng class knows which row is selected... sorry i am new :(

Comment: @charlietfl can you explain me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `ng-class` directive provided by AngularJS.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Change

```
<tr ng-repeat="todoList in todoLists">
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="todoList in todoLists" ng-class="{yellow: editMode && $index == ind}">
```

Answer (score 1):

[Quick and ugly example](http://jsfiddle.net/aks8q70f/), based on your fiddle. You basically want to use `ng-class` to run a function that returns a class if a condition is met. In this case, when you select a todo to edit, you can set that as the selectedTodo on $scope:

```
  $scope.edit = function(index){
      $scope.selectedToDo = $scope.todoLists[index];
      ....
  };
```

And then you can set an `ng-class` on your `<tr>` element that will check if that row's todo is selected and return a class, `.highlighted` in this case, if it is.

```
  $scope.isSelected = function(item) {
      if ($scope.selectedToDo === item) {
          return 'highlighted';
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple example use of `ng-class` using the red class you already have in demo

```
<tr ng-repeat="todoList in todoLists" 
    ng-class="{red:active.item == todoList}" 
    ng-click="active.item=todoList">
```

In controller

```
$scope.active={item:null}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `ng-class` to add css class at run time based on `selectedIndex`, which holds the index of current row in edit mode.

**HTML Code:**

```
  <tr ng-repeat="todoList in todoLists" ng-class="{'yellow':selectedIndex== $index }">
```

**Angular JS Code:**

```
 $scope.edit = function(index) {
   $scope.selectedIndex = index;
   ...
 };

 //clear the selectedIndex to negative index -1
  $scope.update = function(item) {
  if (!$scope.newItem == "") {
     $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
     ...
  };
```

[Live Demo @JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/mcVfK/1353/)

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way to assign different class for different rows

```
ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'"
```

code below

```
<ol ng-init="names=['John', 'Mary', 'Cate', 'Suz']">
  <li ng-repeat="name in names">
   <span ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
     {{name}} &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
   </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

css

```
.odd {
  color: red;
}
.even {
  color: blue;
}
```

but the only thing is this directive can be applied only within the scope of an `ngRepeat`.

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement this.A quick solution would be to pass the `$event` through the edit method of the particular row.

```
<a class="btn {{disabled}} pull-right" href="" ng-click="edit($index,$event)">edit</a> </td>
```

Then your can use $event.target to access the clicked element. You can then use `angular.element($event.target).parent().parent()` to access the row element.

**Edit function**

```
    var EditRow;
    $scope.edit = function(index,$event){
        EditRow = angular.element($event.target).parent().parent(); 
        EditRow.css( "background-color", "#ccc"); // change css style
            $rootScope.ind = index;
            $scope.newItem = $scope.todoLists[$rootScope.ind].name;
            $scope.editMode = true;
            $scope.disabled = "disabled";
            $scope.todoLists[index].edit = "true";
        };
```

**Update function**

```
$scope.update = function(item){
    if(!$scope.newItem == ""){  
            $scope.todoLists[$rootScope.ind].name = item;
            $scope.todoLists[$rootScope.ind].edit = "false";
            $scope.editMode = false;
            $scope.newItem = "";
            $scope.disabled = "";
        }else{
            $scope.empty = true;
        };
    EditRow.css( "background-color", "#fff"); //We change the style back
    };
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qreqk4z/).

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the **jsfiddle** for u: http://jsfiddle.net/mv0ne441/
You can use **ng-class** directive in the table's 'tr' element for the whole row highlighting as you said in the question

```
<tr ng-repeat="todoList in todoLists" ng-class="{true:'yellow', false:'red'} [todoList.edit == 'true']">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{todoList.name}}</td>
    <td>{{todoList.edit}}</td>
    <td><a class="btn {{disabled}} pull-right" href="" ng-click="remove(todoList)">delete</a>
                    <a class="btn {{disabled}} pull-right" href="" ng-click="edit($index)">edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added the update code here please have a look on it .

you should have to use ng-class.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "$rootScope",
  function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.empty = false;
    $scope.editMode = false;

    $scope.todoLists = [{
      name: "one",
      edit: "false",
      "todoeditclick": false
    }, {
      name: "two",
      edit: "false",
      "todoeditclick": false
    }];

    $scope.add = function() {
      if (!$scope.newItem == "") {
        $scope.todoLists.push({
          name: $scope.newItem,
          edit: "false"
        });
        $scope.newItem = "";
        $scope.empty = false;
      } else {
        $scope.empty = true;
      };
    };

    $scope.remove = function(item) {
      var index = $scope.todoLists.indexOf(item);
      $scope.todoLists.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.edit = function(index) {
      $rootScope.ind = index;
      $scope.newItem = $scope.todoLists[$rootScope.ind].name;
      $scope.editMode = true;
      $scope.disabled = "disabled";
      $scope.todoLists[index].edit = "true";
    };

    $scope.update = function(item) {
      if (!$scope.newItem == "") {
        $scope.todoLists[$rootScope.ind].name = item;
        $scope.todoLists[$rootScope.ind].edit = "false";
        $scope.todoLists[$rootScope.ind].todoeditclick = false;
        $scope.editMode = false;
        $scope.newItem = "";
        $scope.disabled = "";

      } else {
        $scope.empty = true;
      };
    };


  }
]);
```

```css
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h3>Todo List</h3>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="create your todos" ng-model="newItem">
    <p class="help-block text-center red" ng-show="!newItem && empty">*Fill the field.</p>
    <br>




    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Todo</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="todoList in todoLists" ng-class="{yellow:todoList.todoeditclick}">
          <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
          <td>{{todoList.name}}</td>
          <td>{{todoList.edit}}</td>
          <td><a class="btn {{disabled}} pull-right" href="" ng-click="remove(todoList)">delete</a>
            <a class="btn {{disabled}} pull-right" href="" ng-click="edit($index);todoList.todoeditclick=!todoeditclick">edit</a> 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>



    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="add()" ng-hide="editMode">ADD</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="update(newItem)" ng-show="editMode">UPDATE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```